Why might a discriminator (for a modified WGAN architecture) with a non-singlular output perform better than traditional discriminator?
The following are the Generator and Discriminator model architectures for a (modified) WGAN model that I have come up with for downsampling rainfall data by a factor of 4 (only as a test). The input shape of the dataset is (8030, 14, 21) and the output shape I want is (8030, 28, 42).
def build_generator(input_shape):
   inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='generator_input')

   # Downsampling
   downsample_3 = conv_block(inputs, 128, (3, 3), 'downsample_3')
   downsample_2 = conv_block(downsample_3, 64, (3, 3), 'downsample_2')
   downsample_1 = conv_block(downsample_2, 32, (3, 3), 'downsample_1')

   # Bottleneck
   bottleneck_0 = conv_block(downsample_1, 16, (3, 3), 'bottleneck_0')
   bottleneck_00 = conv_block(bottleneck_0, 16, (3, 3), 'bottleneck_00')

   # Upsampling
   upsample_1 = deconv_block(bottleneck_00, 32, (3, 3), 'upsample_1')
   upsample_2 = deconv_block(upsample_1, 64, (3, 3), 'upsample_2')
   upsample_3 = deconv_block(upsample_2, 128, (3, 3), 'upsample_3')

   # Final Upsample to required shape
   outputs = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), kernel_initializer=he_normal(), padding='same', 
                          strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', name='final_upsample_conv')(upsample_3)

   model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='generator')

   return model

def build_discriminator(input_shape):
   input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape, name='discriminator_input')

   x = conv_block(input_layer, filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='conv1')#, use_batch_norm=False)
   x = conv_block(x, filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='conv2')# use_batch_norm=False)
   x = conv_block(x, filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), name='conv3')# use_batch_norm=False)

   x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
   x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
   output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

   model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='discriminator')

   return model

Going by WGAN implementations in the literature I use the RMSprop optimizer instead of ADAM with a learning rate of 5e-5 and momentum of 0.5. Additionally I clip the discriminator weights to fall between -1e-2 and 1e-2. Traditionally (to the best of my knowledge), discriminator models output a single value loss conveying whether it is able to distinguish real output from fake outputs. In my case the discriminator output has the shape (None, 14, 21, 1) and it seems to work better but I don't understand why. Does anyone have an idea why this might happen? Thanks in advance!
Edit: These are the architectures of conv_block and deconv_block
def conv_block(x, filters, kernel_size, name, use_batch_norm=True):
   x = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same', kernel_initializer=he_normal(), name=name+'_conv')(x)
   x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name=name+'_lrelu')(x)
   if use_batch_norm:
       x = BatchNormalization(name=name+'_bn')(x)
   x = Dropout(0.25, name=name+'_dropout')(x)
   return x

def deconv_block(x, filters, kernel_size, name, use_batch_norm=True):
   x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same', kernel_initializer=he_normal(), name=name+'_deconv')(x)
   x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name=name+'_lrelu')(x)
   if use_batch_norm:
       x = BatchNormalization(name=name+'_bn')(x)
   return x

Edit 2: Here are the loss functions
def generator_loss(fake_output, real_output, penalty_weight=10):
"""
   Generator loss function using Wasserstein loss with an added penalty term.

   Parameters:
    fake_output (tf.Tensor): Output of the discriminator when given generated images.
    real_output (tf.Tensor): Output of the discriminator when given real images.
    penalty_weight (float): Weight of the penalty term.

Returns:
    tf.Tensor: Generator loss.
"""
   wasserstein_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(fake_output)

   # Penalty term for deviation from real outputs
   penalty = penalty_weight * tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(fake_output - real_output))

   return wasserstein_loss + penalty


def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
"""
   Discriminator loss function using Wasserstein loss.

   Parameters:
    real_output (tf.Tensor): Output of the discriminator when given real images.
    fake_output (tf.Tensor): Output of the discriminator when given generated images.

Returns:
    tf.Tensor: Discriminator loss.
"""
   return tf.reduce_mean(fake_output) - tf.reduce_mean(real_output)


This can't really be answered without seeing the loss function definition, but presumably your discriminator is acting in a "local" fashion on input windows, similar to PatchGAN, which may be easier to learn.

Okay, I've added the loss functions. But I see your point. Makes a lot of sense to me why this would make a difference in rainfall field. To be honest, the discriminator architecture was an accident, but good to know that it was a happy accident. Thanks @xdurch  for your input. I'll wait to see if anyone else has other opinions.
